# Asp.net Redirecting from Https to Http

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect

I am trying to redirect from secure (https) to http when user login. It redirects fine but for some reason its keeping the https.

```
 Response.Redirect(RedirectPath)
```

`RedirectPath` contains fully qualified URL including http.

for example `RedirectPath = "http://www.mydomain.com"`

but it redirects to the `https://www.mydomain.com`

Comment: Sounds like something else is causing this re-direction to https?  If you are confident that your redirect variable is fully qualified and http then it's something outside of this piece of code.  What version of IIS is it? Do you have any Url re-writes in there or anything?

Comment: How about rewrite rules so don't perform redirect manually (programmatically), but let do this by the web server?

Comment: yes i am fully confident that Code is fine. We have two load balanced server for secure website. We are using IIS7. It works fine on local and project environment but it does not work on Test Environment.

Comment: we have no URL rewriting in Secure project.

Comment: I am not sure what is causing this issue. But it could be because of Load Balancing. I have seen from Fiddler as well its moving to ( moved object 302 ) http but destination is https.

Answer (score 5):

I redirect by running the following on `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            var ub = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
            ub.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
            ub.Port = -1; // use default port for scheme
            Response.Redirect(ub.Uri.ToString(), true);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can similarly go from https to http by setting the Scheme to `UriSchemeHttp` if `IsSecureConnection` is true.

Comment: I'm going to up-vote this because you've just introduced me to the UriBuilder class :-)

Comment: No it does not help. But i can still try and let you know

Comment: @Mantorok - It's a good class, but not as fully featured as you would like ;) Would be really nice if it had things like `AddQueryString(string key, string value)` which could handle the whole "is there already a query string set, in which case I'll append with & otherwise I'll use ?".

Comment: @Zhaph, ah, I did wonder if it had such a method, because I've had to write my own in the past! Although not a horrendous amount of work, UriBuilder does seem to be a lot cleaner than my current url-restructuring code though.

Comment: WARNING: be very careful about using Uri.ToString method. it is does NOT properly URL encode the parameters so it's really only suitable for novelty purposes or logging, not redirecting. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx

Comment: @Andy: good point about Uri.ToString. I think Uri.OriginalString would probably be a better choice there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my 2 cents...

Make a simple attribute class like this:

```
public class ForceSSL : System.Attribute{

public bool Enabled;

public ForceSSL(bool _enabled)
    Enabled = _enabled; }
```

Next, create a base class for your page(s) to inherit from. Inside the base class override the OnPreInit event as such (building from the example above @ Druid):

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        var _sslAttr = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(at => (at as ForceSSL) != null).FirstOrDefault();
        if (_sslAttr != null)
        {
            if ((_sslAttr as ForceSSL).Enabled)
            {
                var ub = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
                ub.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
                ub.Port = -1;
                Response.Redirect(ub.Uri.ToString(), true);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Now just make your pages inherit from your base class and place the attribute [ForceSSL(true)] at the top of each page that you want to access via SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you take a look at the requests with a tool such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), to see where these redirects are coming from, and indeed to confirm that `RedirectPath` is indeed fully qualified?

You should be able to confirm that the credentials are being sent over HTTPS, and that you are then redirected (using a 302) to HTTP. If you're redirected to HTTPS, then it's likely that you're not setting the fully qualified domain.

The other alternative is that you are indeed redirecting to an HTTP page, but there's something else that's then forcing the user back to HTTPS - for example the mechanism that forced the user to HTTPS for the login - is this a per page or per directory setting? In which case you'd see a 302 to HTTP, followed by another 302 to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer - I was involved in the development of this project*

I would recommend using http://nuget.org/packages/SecurePages/ It gives you the ability to secure specific pages or use Regex to define matches. It will also force all pages not matching the Regex or directly specified back to HTTP.

You can install it via NuGet: `Install-Package SecurePages`

Docs are here: https://github.com/webadvanced/Secure-Page-manager-for-asp.net#secure-pages

Simple Usage:

```
SecurePagesConfiguration.Urls.AddUrl("/cart");
```

or

```
SecurePagesConfiguration.Urls.AddRegex(@"(.*)account", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue and in my case it's definitely being rewritten by the load balancer. We're using an Equalizer from CoyotePoint. I just read the following in the manual:

> In a Layer 7 HTTPS cluster, clients connect to the cluster IP using
>   HTTPS connections. Equalizer terminates the HTTPS connection and
>   communicates with the servers in the cluster using the HTTP protocol.
>   By default, Equalizer examines server responses for http:// URLs and
>   rewrites them as https:// URLs, so that these URLs work properly on
>   the client. If, for example, a server sends an HTTP redirect using the
>   Location: header, this URL most likely will include the http://
>   protocol. Equalizer rewrites this response so that the URL uses
>   https://.

Apparently, I can disable "no header rewrite" to correct it.