# Response.redirect cannot redirect to a non-secure site

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

I have a ASP.Net application which is securely hosted and uses https. 
I need to navigate to site which is not secured.

I have a aspx page in ASP.net website (which uses https). And on page_load of this aspx page, I am using Response.Redirect as below, if try to navigate to http site, it doesn't work but works for https site,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.cnn.com", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a bit more detail? when you say it doesn't work, what are you directed to, and what are you expecting to be directed to?

Comment: I think that's a browser restriction, if you are navigating in a https site it will not redirect to a http one, try with other browser (to test if that's the case)

Comment: Wow. That was a poor title. Can you see why the title I just changed it to is better?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should terminate the current page execution:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.cnn.com", true);
```

By the way here is an another problem, but it says the redirection is working: [Asp.net Redirecting from Https to Http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569643/asp-net-redirecting-from-https-to-http)